# How to use background image?

Tags: html, webpack, twig, tailwind-css

I use Symfony framework. I want to add an backgroun image to my element with Tailwindcss framework.

I use this in `index.html.twig` :

```
<div class="w-full bg-[url('{{ asset('images/background.png') }}')]"></div>
```

When run `npm run watch` and go to browser, it create `<div class="w-full bg-[url('/images/background.png')]"></div>` but `background.png` not show and `background-image: url(/images/background.png);` was not created in css file.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix by adding a `style` tag.

```
<div class="w-full" style="background-image:url('{{ asset('images/background.png') }}')"> </div>
```